# How to sync the commands I am typing with a document in Google docs?

Tags: bash

I am working on installation of a software and making lot of changes in a linux box. Lot of times I am running 'history' to get list of commands and copy-paste into a Google Docs. Then I clean it for sharing the steps with the team. Is there a way to setup sync of my command history in a Google doc automatically?

Comment: You might look at `man script` which is a way to preserve your entire terminal session in a file.  More broadly, though, you might consider automating your software installation process with a configuration management solution, e.g. writing a [CFEngine policy](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.21/examples-tutorials-manage-packages.html) or [Ansible playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

For this type of output, i'm setting a rsyslog logger in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
local6.*                                                /var/log/commands.log
```

and a prompt command in `/etc/bashrc`

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

this way you can also log the real user behind a sudoer.

But it will not fillin a Google doc but /var/log/commands.log instead